# How to prevent deletion of Azure SQL db in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, azure

Is there a way to prevent deletion of Azure SQL database within SQL Server Management Studio using one account?

Of course, this is on ONE admin account.

[image]

We tried to follow this URL: https://www.sqlshack.com/protecting-azure-sql-databases-from-accidental-deletion/, but it only prevents it from the Portal?

Comment: Why do you need to modify the permissions of the admin user? Are you talking about the SQL Admin created when the database/server is created? Or the Azure AD Admin? In either case, you should not modify the rights of the admin user and instead restrict access to that account

Comment: Seems like a bug to me if Azure SQL allows this to bypass the lock mechanism. Looks like it was reported here but whoever responded said it should be "copied over to Azure SQL Database" https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/464266dc-5325-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0 - unclear to me where that uservoice site would be if not that one though

Comment: @AnthonyNorwood: Well, we would like to turn off the Drop_Database permission on our admin account. Then have an admin go in and change it when we do need to drop a database, otherwise no one else can, even the Admin account.  We tried the lock resource like Martin Smith mentioned, but it doesn't apply to SSMS for some reason?

Comment: I'm a little confused at what problem you're trying to solve; if an admin has the requisite permissions to grant themselves the ability to drop a database, then what does removing that ability achieve?

Comment: @AnthonyNorwood: Yes, it might not be the exact way you should do it, but only a specific admin(s) can change the permissions on the SQL admin account we use. So if they go in and deny drop database on the account, leave it in place until one actually needs to be deleted, then we can all use the account for developers. Then no one can accidently delete the database in SSMS. Or that is what we are trying to accomplish.

Comment: But why would you give the developers the admin account?

Comment: @AnthonyNorwood - the reasonable expectation from applying a resource delete lock in Azure is that the resource cannot be deleted without taking a conscious decision to remove the lock.

Answer (score 1):

**We tried to follow this URL: [protecting azure sql databases from accidental deletion](https://www.sqlshack.com/protecting-azure-sql-databases-from-accidental-deletion/), but it only prevents it from the Portal?**

As per this [Document](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/protecting-deletions-of-azure-sql-resources/ba-p/368903),

> **While a delete lock on an Azure SQL database will prevent deletion operations through the Azure portal or other Azure tools**,

It will not prevent a user with proper permissions on the SQL Server from deleting the database by executing a T-SQL command like "DROP DATABASE [DATABASENAME]" and through SSMS doesn't know which azure locks applied on Azure SQL database it will delete the database.

If you want to prevent users from deleting Azure SQL databases through T-SQL commands,

- You can use role-based access control (RBAC) to restrict database permissions for specific users or groups.
- By granting only the necessary permissions to users, you can prevent accidental or intentional deletion of important databases.
  --   `CONTROL` permission on the database
  --   Or `ALTER ANY DATABASE`
  --   Or the `db_owner` role in the database.
  mainly these permissions are required to delete database.

Thankfully, the server that the wiped database was on should have the ability to  [restore the deleted database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/recovery-using-backups?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-portal#deleted-database-restore).